# What does the 'which' refer to?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> We understand that the segregation of our consciousness
> into present, past, and future is both a fiction and an oddly
> self-referential framework; your present was part of your
> mother’s future, and your children’s past will be in part your
> present. Nothing is generally wrong with structuring our
> consciousness of time in this conventional manner, and it often
> works well enough. In the case of climate change, however,
> the sharp division of time into past, present, and future has
> been desperately misleading and has, most importantly,
> hidden from view the extent of the responsibility of those of
> us alive now. The narrowing of our consciousness of time
> smooths the way to divorcing ourselves from responsibility
> for developments in the past and the future with **which** our lives
> are in fact deeply intertwined.

Does 'which' refer to 'the past and the future'?

Comment: I think it refers to 'developments'.

Comment: I think we are intertwined with the past, present and future and can't avoid taking responsibility.

Comment: The actual text is ambiguous. In principle, ***which*** could actually just refer back to ***the future***. OR it could refer to ***the past and the future***. OR it could refer to ***developments*** (as it happens, modified by *in the past and the future* - but that entire adjectival element could be removed without significantly affecting either syntax or meaning). To be honest though, it's not obvious to me why *in the past and the future* is specified at all - I doubt the writer intended to exclude ***current*** developments, and "past, current and future developments" is ***everything***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antecedent of "which" should be "the future."

... divorcing ourselves from responsibility for developments in the past and (divorcing ourselves from) [image]the future with which our lives are in fact deeply intertwined.

[image]

I believe 2 is right: what is omitted should be "from responsibility for" since the passage (https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Pivotal_Generation/B1UwEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) goes on talking about our responsibility for past and future.

Comment: Hi Nanhee, what is "2"? Are you referring to one of the comments which had two upvotes? Please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with our platform :) Welcome to ELL!

Comment: by "2," I meant the second picture. what is omitted in the above sentence should be "from responsibility for" (based on the following passage that I linked to), instead of "from."